# upload file in the server

Tags: php, html

//index file

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
    $ch = curl_init();

    $cfile =new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['image']['type'],$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $data = array('myimage' => $cfile);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/curl/send_file_to_server/uploads.php");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if($response == true){
        echo "File Posted";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: ".curl_error($ch);
    }
  }
?>
```

//uploads file

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'])){
    $path = "uploads/".$_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myimage']['name'],$path);
  }
?>
```

Here I want to store an image of index.php into the uploads.php. I am using curl method of php.The file print that file posted but not store in the uploads folder.

Comment: Why are you using cURL here when you seem to just send the file to the same server?

Comment: i am learning cURL.So don't have enough knowledge about it.Follow a tutorial writing the code but it is not working.That's why want help.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to check what your uploads file actually receive? Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and check what that variable contains. You can either do that by logging the result or adding `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true and check the response from the cURL operation. You should also check your servers error log to see if you get any errors in your upload file.

Comment: Yes when i echo $_FILE i got a temporary name.

Comment: You echo it in your upload file, not your index file? Did you check the servers error log? Also, it's better to use an absolute path to the upload folder than a relative.

Comment: No i don't check server error log